Highlight characters between asterisk using Regular Expression
I have following sentence:
I need to highlight/bold the characters between ** as shown in the sample text below:
My sample text:
**Uses:** Use shredded mushrooms in **crab, cakes, lobster rolls, or stir-fries**.
Desired output:
**Uses:** Use shredded mushrooms in **crab, cakes, lobster rolls, or stir-fries**.
Code I have written: (?<=\*\*)(.+?)(?=\*\*)
This code is changing all the words to bold.  What am I missing?
I am using Adobe InDesign which uses Boost flavour of regex. Most of the codes written in Notepad++ runs in Indesign.

Ok I have come up this with code (?<=\*\*)(?![\*\s])(.+?)(?=\*\*[\s.])  Looking for a better option.

I have come up with a solution. Here is the code (?<=\*\*)(?:(?!\s\*\*).)*?(?=\*\*) This works perfectly.

I would not use look around for such job.

Find: \*\*(.+?)\*\*
Replace: <bold>$1</bold>

Change <bold> into whatever indesign is using for bold character.

In Indesign, I can make changes to the matched group only. If anything is not in the group, it will be deleted. So, I changed your code to (\*\*)(.+?)(\*\*) and Replace to: $1$2$3. This changes Asterisk to bold. So, bottom line that did not work as expected. Any other suggestions/ideas ? Thanks

@Shahid: What replacement are you doing? How do you define bold in replacement?

I have shared a screenshot here in the link [Screenshot] (https://www.mediafire.com/view/l9objm02p8h2d7r/scr.png/file)   "bold-colored" character style is applied if the code matches. At the background of the screenshot you can see the sentence in Magenta color. I just want the sentence/word enclosed between asterisks to be bold-coloured.

@Shahid: I see. The only way I've found is to do the job in 2 passes. 1- apply the modification to **text**; 2- revert the style for **

Thanks. I will follow that process.

@Shahid: Nice, you can propose your own answer and accept it.

Thanks. How do I propose my own comment and accept it as an answer. I could not find any option here.

@Shahid: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Try this regex:
(?<=[\s]\*\*)(.+?)(?=\*\*[\s|\.])

It assumes that the words to be bolded directly follow or precede the asterixes. You may need to add some other characters (commas, semicolons, etc...) between the square brackets.

It is ignoring **Uses:**.  It seems to be very close.

InDesign doesn't support a marker for the start of a story. The regex above will bold **Uses:** as long as it it not on the first line of the story
